# Internal Server Error

Tags: .htaccess

I have a copy of a project from internet but I can't run it. It shows error `Internal Server Error` so I can't run this project.

Here is my `.htacces` file:

```
<Files '.ht*'>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</Files>


#suPHP_ConfigPath http://localhost:81/job/

<FilesMatch ".(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|js|css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>

Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
php_value output_buffering On

RewriteRule job-([0-9]+)-(.*)/?$ ./?p=job&id=$1
RewriteRule job-([0-9]+)/?$ ./?p=job&id=$1

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

# compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
```

Answer (score 2):

You're probably missing a module on your Apache installation (for example `mod_headers`).

This `.htaccess` should include `IfModule` directives to prevent this kind of error:

```
<Files '.ht*'>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>


#suPHP_ConfigPath http://localhost:81/job/
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch ".(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|js|css)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Options -Multiviews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    php_value output_buffering On

    RewriteRule job-([0-9]+)-(.*)/?$ ./?p=job&id=$1
    RewriteRule job-([0-9]+)/?$ ./?p=job&id=$1
</IfModule>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

# compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
<IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>

# remove browser bugs
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
        BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
        Header append Vary User-Agent
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

You should check that your Apache installation includes those modules:

- mod_headers
- mod_rewrite
- mod_expires
- mod_filter
- mod_setenvif